# Comparing to strings but no effect

Tags: c#, string

So I have a list of terminals: a, b, c, d

I have a production like

```
 A > aA | cC |a
```

I'm trying to check if a part of production A is a terminal or if that part exists in list of terminals. The problem is that when I compare the two parts the result is always false. I have tried with "Equals", "Contains" and "==" and the result is the same and I don't know why.

My code from where I split the production and compare the two parts:

```
foreach (Production production in productions)
            {

                String prod = production.ToString();
                String[] right = prod.Trim().Split('>');
                String justRightPart = right[1];
                String[] separate = justRightPart.Trim().Split('|');
                Boolean ok = true;
                foreach (String s in separate)
                {
                        foreach(string terminal in terminals)
                        {
                           Console.WriteLine("Terminal: " + terminal + " string part  is " +s);
                           Boolean bool = terminal.Contains(s) || (terminal == s);
                           Console.WriteLine("bool : " + bool);
                         }
             }
        }
```

and the bool is always false even if it says:

```
 Terminal a string part is a
```

Why is not equal?
Any suggestions?

Comment: A string should be compared using Equals() method

Comment: I don't believe that this code is compiling.  `Boolean bool = terminal.Contains(s) || (terminal == s);` => `bool` is a reserved keyword by C# and cannot be used as an identifier. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx

Comment: Given that string input, the contents of `separate` would be `{ "aA ", " cC ", "a"}`. (Notice the spaces.)

Comment: Well, I write it here that way but in the file there is no space @Abion47

Comment: @Adiiia Then give us that. We can't help you properly if you give us data/code that your program doesn't actually use.

Comment: Shouldn't _"terminal.Contains(s)"_ be _"s.Contains(terminal)"_ ("a" cannot contain "aA"). That way _"terminal == s"_ is not required.

Comment: I would suggest editing your question to remove the words "production" and "terminal" as they aren't really relevant to the question - you're just dealing with `string`s, so make it a question about `string`s.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably whitespace in `s` that isn't in `terminal` or vice versa. Try adding single quotes around your string printing, eg:

```
Console.WriteLine("Terminal: '" + terminal + "' string part is '" + s + "'");
```

It might be clearer if you rewrite your print using positional arguments, eg:

```
Console.WriteLine("Terminal: '{0}' string part is '{1}'", terminal, s);
```

Comment: Yes, I have space in string. But how to delete it because in the string there is parts of productions from my file where I have no space?

Comment: @Adiiia  Don't forget to accept my answer if it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using *Linq*, e.g.

```
  List<String> terminals = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" };

  string source = "A > aA | cC | a";

  var hasTerminal = source
    .Substring(source.IndexOf('>') + 1) // at the right of ">"
    .Split('|')                         // split to parts 
    .Select(part => part.Trim())        // trim each part (leading/trailing white spaces)
    .Any(part => terminals.Contains(part)); // ... if part exists in list of terminals
```

You may want to implement a *debugging report* / log as well:

```
var report = source
  .Substring(source.IndexOf('>') + 1)
  .Split('|')
  .Select(part => part.Trim())
  .Select(part => $"{part,4} is {(terminals.Contains(part) ? "a term" : "NOT a term")}");

Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, report));
```

The outcome is

```
aA is NOT a term
cC is NOT a term
 a is a term
```